# Does every inner product space have a maximal orthonormal set?

Tags: functional-analysis

I know that this statement is true for Hilbert spaces and the proof uses Zorn's lemma along with Gram-Schmidt, but it seems that the proof also works for just regular inner product spaces, i.e., pre-Hilbert spaces. Is this true?

Comment: I don't get your question. If the proof works for any inner product space, then the statement is true for any inner product space.

Comment: Hilbert spaces are complete inner product spaces. I'm asking if the statement is true if we don't assume completeness

Comment: i know. and it seems like you said you think the proof doesn't use completeness. so what's the issue?

Comment: Well, I actually just wanted to check if anyone knows this from some literature, because I didn't prove it step by step.

Comment: ok, i was confused because your second comment is a really bad response to my first comment.

Comment: You can find a nice discussion of this topic in *Fourier and Wavelet Analysis* by Bachman, Narici, and Beckenstein, section 3.4. Your hunch is true.